# ActiveRecord: search by array field element inside another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an object with an array field, called emails

```
user.emails = ['a@b.c','d@e.f']
```

I want to find all the users from a list of emails:

```
emails_to_find = ['a@b.c','x@y.z']
```

I tried running

```
User.where(emails: emails_to_find)
```

but I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

How do I do that? What the error means?

Answer (score 3):

If the column is of type `Array` and in the migration that created it you have something like `t.string 'emails', array: true`, try using:

```
User.where("emails @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ['a@b.c','d@e.f'])
User.where("'a@b.c' = ANY (emails)")
```